What happens when a company moves its listing between stock exchanges?
There's a lot of talk about Ocado moving its listing from London to the US (presumably NASDAQ) - see this for one example of a story. What happens to ordinary shareholders in this situation? Does the stock get bought as it would in an acquisition scenario, or would the shares be exchanged for the new listing?

Where the stock is listed will not have any effect on your ownership. You will not be forced to sell your shares just because they change what exchange they are traded on.
Now, depending on your ability to trade on the NASDAQ, you may decide to sell your shares before the move so you don't lose the ability to sell them, but you will not be forced to sell them.
Changing exchanges can have different effects on shareholders in general, mostly around liquidity (the ability to buy/sell easily), and the change of listing may affect price indirectly as the investor base changes (which seems to be the motivation for this specific listing change), but there is no direct effect on shareholder value.
